# React useEffect how it works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using firebase cloud for databases.
This useEffect reads every doc from the collection("emails)"

As I know useEffect will run every time component load or 
when some data change if we set it in [ ] `( useEffect() => {}, []);`

But my question is how do my component know to "rerender the whole list" when I send mail(update "emails"). When I do not have anything in last []

Also have problem with my project gmail clone if someone can check last post.

[React.js + REDUX... I don't know, for some reson when I remove star from starred section, it render me "emails"(all inbox) not "starredEmails"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739606/react-js-redux-i-dont-know-for-some-reson-when-i-remove-star-from-starred)

```
useEffect(() => {
        const readData = () => {
            db.collection("emails") // uzimi emails kolekciju
                .orderBy("timestamp", "desc") // rapsoredi ih po timestampu
                .onSnapshot((
                    snapshot // uzmi snapshot trenutni
                ) =>
                    setEmails(
                        // stavi mail da bude ovo
                        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                            id: doc.id, // id = doc.id nDqpnWjBpy....
                            data: doc.data(), // ovo je zapravo message,subject,to itd..
                        }))
                    )
                );
        };
}, []);
```

Comment: The second parameter you pass to `useEffect` is a list of state values that determine when the `useEffect` handler will run again. In other words, the handler you have will only run one time with the way you have it right now. It shouldn't be rerendering.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But when I send mail. New mail just add on-screen it rerenders for some reason. You can even try it here this is my clone <https://clone-3857a.firebaseapp.com/>

Comment: Because you subscribe for changes to the collection by calling `onSnapshot`. So every time it emits an event, your `setEmail` is called, hence the component re-renders. Please note, it would be appropriate to unsubscribe from the changes. You can use return value of `onSnapshot` to unsubscribe. Simply return that function in your `useEffect` as [cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

Answer (score 0):

You just defined the `readData` function inside the `componentDidMount` hook, and you probably use it somewhere further in your component. Remember that the definition is not the same as invoking. And also remember that React re-renders a componenr anytime any value (prop/state) changes.

So a way to avoid what you said would be implementing a `setErrors` conditionally, like this:

```
setEmails(prevState => {
    if (prevState === []) {  // updating only initially, pass your initial emails' value here
       return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data()
        }));
    } else return prevState;
)
```